# AMD APU Kabini - OpenCL

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, opencl

What’s the best combination of Ubuntu and AMD software in order to have Kabini APU/GPU running with OpenCL?

I’ve tried 16.04.x, 14.04.5, open source and AMD’s closed drivers. Nothing works.

This is what I have:

```
root@apucomputer2:~# dmidecode | grep AMD

Manufacturer: AuthenticAMD

Version: AMD Sempron™ 3850 APU with Radeon™ R3

root@apucomputer2:~#

root@apucomputer2:~# lspci | grep VGA

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD >8280 / R3 Series]

root@apucomputer2:~#

root@apucomputer2:~#

root@apucomputer2:~# uname -a

Linux apucomputer2.nuo.com.mx 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@apucomputer2:~#

root@apucomputer2:~# cat /etc/issue

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked on Ubuntu 14.04.2. It has to be the exact patch level ...2. Amazing.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

OpenCL working:

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1912.5)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               2
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                     1002h
  Board name:                    
  Device Topology:               PCI[ B#0, D#1, F#0 ]
  Max compute units:                 2
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               256
    Max work items[1]:               256
    Max work items[2]:               256
  Max work group size:               256
  Preferred vector width char:           4
  Preferred vector width short:          2
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          4
  Native vector width short:             2
  Native vector width int:           1
  Native vector width long:          1
  Native vector width float:             1
  Native vector width double:            1
  Max clock frequency:               450Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             194992128
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       128
  Max number of images write arguments:      64
  Max image 2D width:                16384
  Max image 2D height:               16384
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            16
  Max size of kernel argument:           1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      2048
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     No
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               64
  Cache size:                    16384
  Global memory size:                779968512
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           8
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 32768
  Max pipe arguments:                16
  Max pipe active reservations:          16
  Max pipe packet size:              194992128
  Max global variable size:          175492864
  Max global variable preferred total size:  779968512
  Max read/write image args:             64
  Max on device events:              1024
  Queue on device max size:          8388608
  Max on device queues:              1
  Queue on device preferred size:        262144
  SVM capabilities:              
    Coarse grain buffer:             Yes
    Fine grain buffer:               Yes
    Fine grain system:               No
    Atomics:                     No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:       0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:         0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:      0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     64
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        1
  Profiling timer resolution:            1
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue on Host properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:                
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Platform ID:                   0x7fd39b7aca18
  Name:                      Kalindi
  Vendor:                    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 2.0 
  Driver version:                1912.5 (VM)
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1912.5)
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_depth_images cl_ext_atomic_counters_32 cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_spir cl_khr_subgroups cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_mipmap_image cl_khr_mipmap_image_writes
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using Fedora, but have spent far more time on this than my little A4-5000 is worth =)

The conclusion I reached is that the AMDGPU driver should have limited support for Kabini, but needs the IOMMU enabled.  If your BIOS doesn't support IOMMU, you are out of luck.

Of course I would love to hear a happier story from someone who is better informed.